# why the flow is not proceeding to the base class constructor at first?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

As per the understanding once the child class constructor is called the parent class constructor will get executed first and the control will pass over to the child class constructor. But in the following program, the child class parametrized constructor gets executed, and then the program flow proceeds accordingly.

when the base class doesn't have a default constructor (has a parameterized constructor) we need to use super() in the first line of the child parametrized constructor. Here we are invoking this(), so do we have any specific rules for the following program behavior.

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        System.out.println("Parent's default constructor");
    }

    Parent(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("Parents parametrized constructor" + name);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        System.out.println("child's default constructor ");
    }

    Child(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("childs parametrized constructor"+ name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child("Test"); 
    }
}
```

Expected O/p
Parent's default constructor
Parent's default constructor
child's default constructor
childs parametrized constructor

Actual O/P
Parent's default constructor
child's default constructor
childs parametrized constructor

Comment: Why do you expect two times "Parent's default constructor"? It is unclear to me, what is unclear to you ...

Comment: `this()` refers to the same class, maybe you meant to use `super()`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Because I was expecting the child class constructor (child(String name)) to invoke parent class default constructor before executing itself.

Comment: Yes, it does so! Once! I asked you, why you do expect it twice?

Comment: @MrNolan The super constructor is only called once for each object. There's no reason to call it twice. After that, you might call a constructor in the same class.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose First is when I access Child(String name) and the second time is when I access the child's default constructor Child()

Comment: When you invoke the constructor `Child(String name)`, you are explicitely calling the constructor with `this()`. So no `super()` call is invoked here!

Comment: The superclass's constructor is only called once. In `Child(String name)`, you are not calling `super()`, you're calling `this()`, which calls `super()`. It wouldn't make sense for the constructor to be called twice - that would mean you're setting fields twice

Comment: okay, I got it, if we don't have this() inside the child's constructor then it invokes the parent default constructor directly. if I include this() then the control goes inside the child's default constructor and then to the parent's default constructor.  The compiler smartly decides it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Child extends Parent { 
   Child() {
        // single implicit super() call here
        System.out.println("child's default constructor ");
    }

    Child(String name) {
        this(); // takes the place of implicit super() call
        System.out.println("childs parameterized constructor "+ name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child("Test"); 
    }
}
```

- Case 1.  no `this()` in parameterized child's constructor.  So implicit `super()` is invoked once in same constructor
- Case 2.  `this()` in parameterized child's constructor.  No implicit `super()` invoked here but invoked in child's default constructor once.